# Can the decision version of an optimization problem in NP, be in P?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, decision-problem

It is well known that a optimization problem can be turned into a decision problem with an extra parameter: e.g. in TSP we are looking for the lowest cost for a tour, the decision version therefore could check whether a a tour exists which costs at most $K$.

Lets assume we are talking about an optimization problem which is either NP or NP-hard. Can the corresponding decision problem ever be in P?

NB: What I am trying to ask is: if a optimization problem cannot be solved in polynomial time, can the corresponding decision problem be solve in polynomial time?

Answer (score 4):

Optimization problems cannot belong to NP or be NP-hard any more than apples. NP is a class of *decision problems*, and NP-hardness is a property of *decision problems*. When we say that an optimization problem is in NP or is NP-hard, what we really mean is that the *corresponding decision problem* is in NP or is NP-hard.

Comment: You're right about optimization problems not being in NP, but NP-hard does not only contain decision problems but also optimization problems.

Anyway what I want to ask is: if a optimization problem cannot be solved in polynomial time, can the corresponding decision problem be solve in polynomial time?

Comment: No, actually I'm right about NP-hardness as well.

Comment: The more interesting direction is the other one: if the decision version is in P, can we solve the original version in polynomial time? This is the case if, for example, the optimal value is a polynomial-size integer, and the idea is to use binary search (details left to you).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus To be fair, NP-hardness is sometimes used in the context of optimization problems, e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness): "It does not restrict the class NP-hard to decision problems, for instance it also includes search problems, or optimization problems."

Comment: @Tom The same is true for NP. For example, when we say that Max Clique is an NP-complete problem, we are implying that the optimization problem Max Clique is in NP. What we really mean is that the *decision version* of Max Clique is in NP. Therefore, *by definition*, if an optimization problem is in NP (or NP-hard) then its decision version is in NP (or NP-hard).

Comment: I thought your argument was concerning whether an optimization problem could be NP-hard, I see now what you were getting at.