# Is the Maximum Independent Set problem NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, np-hard, np

[It can be read on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) that MIS is NP-hard. However, is it also NP-complete?

[This article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00908) says:

> "Thus, the Maximum Clique Problem(MCP) and the Maximum Independent
> Set(MIS) Problem are equivalent. In addition, both problems are
> NP—complete".

However, a professor told me that MIS cannot be NP-complete because only decision problems can be NP-complete. According to him, MIS is an optimization problem, and therefore it is not in NP.

Comment: There are many relevant questions already answered on this site, for example https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/939/optimization-version-of-decision-problems, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79707/does-every-computational-problem-have-a-decision-version, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56518/can-the-decision-version-of-an-optimization-problem-in-np-be-in-p.

Comment: and also https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/982/755